# Subpages return 404 server error

Tags: redirect, htaccess, 404-error, server, paths

I just moved a site to another production environment and I have an issue with accessing subpages. The home page and the /wp-admin section works as expected and there are no path issues with images or other files.

My permalinks are set to /%category%/%postname%/, but neither that or using a default url such as http://site.com/?p=123 works for the subpages ("The requested URL /sample-page/ was not found on this server.").

I've searched and replaced all absolute paths to point to the local environment.

Htaccess set to

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Running on Apache with Polylang (set to not show prefix at default language) and ACF plugins.

Edit: Solved! AllowOverride was turned off for my /www directory in the Apache main config.

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled at all? is the 404 generate by apach or wordpress?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, yes it is enabled / loaded (checked via phpinfo).

Comment: please make a proper answer from how you fixed it.